# HttpClient 4.x hangs on socketRead(Native Method)

Tags: java, sockets, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm calling a remote REST service using `HttpClient- 4.3.4`. Client hangs at this line and finally throws back ReadTimeOut exception.

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead#(Native Method)
```

Request volume is almost millions in a day and I get ~1% of ReadTimeOut error. It happens intermittently. I have set the timeout to 6 sec and that's the reason I'm getting timeout exception otherwise I assume it would have hanged for longer. I have enabled the StaleConnectionCheck as well. I looked at the service provider response time and service is responding within 100 ms.

```
public MyRespBean doGet(
      String host, String path, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs, Map<String, String> headers)
      throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

      CloseableHttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
      URI uri = buildUri(host, path, nameValuePairs);
      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
      httpGet.setHeader("Connection", "close");
      addHeaders(httpGet, headers, authParams);
      MyRespBean respBean = httpClient.execute(httpGet, new SimpleResponseHandler());
      httpClient.close();
      return respBean;
  }



public CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient() {
   CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
   RequestConfig requestConfig = null;
   if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(proxyHost) && proxyPort != null && StringUtils
       .isNotBlank(proxyScheme)) {
       HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort, proxyScheme);
       requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(6000).setConnectTimeout(6000)
                      .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(true).setProxy(proxy)
                      .build();

   } else {
       requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(6000).setConnectTimeout(6000)
                      .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(true).build();
   }
   httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
   return httpClient;
}
```

Maven depedency

```
   `enter code here`<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I looked at some other post where suggestion was to -

1. set timeout (which is not actually a solution and anyway I've set it)
2. Service Provider might be taking longer time - (Not in my case)
3. There could be StaleConnection - (I'm already checking for that)

What could cause such issue ?

Comment: Most likely that simply means the opposite endpoint failed to produce any data after 6000 milliseconds of inactivity

Comment: @oleg I've mentioned in my problem statement that service returns response within 100 ms... I verified again and I don't have any request in which service took more than 100 ms.